# ¿Cómo puedo forzar el "Modo Obscuro" en Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

Yo para el *Modo Obscuro* en *Assets* creé colores con *Appearance: "Any, Dark"* para que cuando el usuario ponga el modo obscuro se cambie automáticamente.
Mi pregunta es, teniendo así configurado el modo obscuro y a pesar de que el usuario no tenga el modo obscuro activado, estuve investigando pero no encuentro la solución.

¿Se puede forzar mediante un *Switch* a que la aplicación si esté en modo obscuro?

Comment: Hola recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] , edita tu pregunta por favor. saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más fácil es forzar el modo oscuro de toda tu App en el Info.Plist, poniendo el *Value* **Dark** en el *Key* **User Interface Style**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado, si quieres cambiar dinámicamente el modo de la App tendrás que crear una función que utilice tu **AppDelegate**, por ejemplo cuando uses tu Switch:

SWIFT:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
}
```

OBJ-C

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleDark;
}
```

Comment: Si me funcionó, muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 0):

Modifica tu info.plist y agrega la llave "Appearance" con valor "Dark"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]